# SweetAlert 2 Mask Input

Tags: reactjs, masking, sweetalert2

I'm using Sweet Alert2 (https://sweetalert2.github.io/) -react component and I need on second step mask the input with (thousand separator and prefix="$") it's possible?

**Here some code**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
    import { Fab } from '@material-ui/core';
    import withReactContent from 'sweetalert2-react-content';


    const reSwal = withReactContent(Swal);

    class NewTask extends Component {


      state = {
        goToProfile: false
      };


      handleNewTask = async () => {

        reSwal.mixin({
          input: 'text',
          confirmButtonText: 'Next →',
          showCancelButton: true,
          progressSteps: ['1', '2']
        }).queue([
          {
            title: 'Age',
            text: 'Your Age'
          },
          {
            title: 'Budget',
            text: 'Your Budget',
            input: 'number',
            inputAttributes: {
              min: 100,
              max: 1000000
            },
          },

        ]).then((result) => {
          if (result.value) {
            reSwal.fire({
              title: 'thank u !',
              confirmButtonText: 'Lovely!'
            })
          }
        })
      }

      render() {

        return (
          
            New
          
        );
      }
    }

    export default NewTask;
```

I don't know how to control this. Thank for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know that already passed 3 months, but I hope I can still help you.

I got this problem just now and googled for answers but didn't get any solution, so I used this method to achieve what I wanted:

```
swal.fire({
    text: 'myText',
    input: 'text',
    inputAttributes: {
        id: 'myInput'
    },
    onOpen: function(el) {
        var container = $(el);
        container.find('#myInput').mask('$ 0000.00');
    }
```

That solution uses the Jquery's Mask Plugin ([you can see the documentation here](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html)) and the `onOpen` attribute from SweetAlert2.
At `onOpen`, you can pass a function that gets the swal container, finds the input by id with JQuery and calls the `.mask()` method with the mask you asked for.

At the Jquery's Mask Plugin official site you can see more examples of masks.

Good afternoon!

Comment: To anyone looking for this answer after 3 years. This still works like a charm, the only difference is that the property now is didOpen, and not onOpen as stated in this example, but definitely still works.

Answer (score 0):

this one may help you, btw i using maskMoney lib for jquery

```
inputAttributes: {
    autocapitalize: 'off',
    id: "maskInput",
},
onOpen: function (el) {
    var container = $(el);
    container.find('#maskInput').maskMoney({ thousands:'.', decimal:',', affixesStay: false, precision: 0});
    container.find('#maskInput').keyup(function(e){
        $(this).maskMoney('mask', $(this).val(), { thousands:'.', decimal:',', affixesStay: false, precision: 0});
    });
},
```